# GitHub rechaza mis actualizaciones a mi repositorio

Tags: github

Hace unos días atrás acababa de hacer una actualización a un repositorio de **GitHub** y hasta ese momento todo estaba bien. Luego me fije que aparecía un mensaje a bajo de los archivos de mi repositorio de **GitHub** donde decía que añadiera un `README` ni siquiera se para que se utiliza pero de todos modos decidí añadirlo al repositorio.

Luego de un día escribiendo código a mi proyecto, decidí guardar las nuevas actualizaciones en **GitHub** pero esta no se me están guardado porque me esta lanzando un error cuando escribo el comando `git push` después de colocar mi usuario y contraseña.

**Este es el error que me esta mostrando por pantalla:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Espero puedan ayudarme, un saludo.*

Comment: tienes que ejecutar un fetch first y es muy probable que pierdas cambios asique copia tus cambios a otro lugar

Comment: O mejor elimino el repositorio y vuelvo a crearlo

Comment: Como bien indica la terminal tienes que hacer un `git pull` primero para bajarte los nuevos cambios del repositorio. Seguidamente vuelve a realizar el push

Comment: @gmarsi Solamente debo de escribir `git pull` y listo ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema se basa en que has añadido un cambio en el repositorio cuando agregaste la actualización del `README`

Lo que debes hacer es entrar a el repositorio con tu consola y escribir lo que se te esta indicando en la consola que es `git pull` una vez escribas este comando te pedirá que coloques tu usuario y contraseña de **GitHub** en la consola. Una vez lo que coloques se mostraran algunas informaciones y lo que tienes que hacer es cerrar la consola y volver abrirla en el repositorio y crear un `git commit -m "Tu cambios"` y luego por ultimo realizar el `git push`